# Need to Export RBAC roles on Subscription, resource group, resource level in Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, rbac

I am trying the available Microsoft gallery script [https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-Azure-Resource-092b9c2a#content] but it's running on subscription level and it's hanging in the middle. Looking for the solution from PowerShell or Microsoft Graph API to pull the required RBAC roles from Subscription, resource groups and each resource level.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left my reply, there is an option to mark), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the command in the script lists all role assignments in the selected Azure subscription by default. You just need to use the parameters e.g.`-ResourceGroupName`, `-Scope` in the command, then you will be able to do what you want.

Besides, in your script, it uses old AzureRm command `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment`, it was deprecated. I recommend you to use `Get-AzRoleAssignment`.

For more details, see this link: [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/Get-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-2.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that you just need to use `Get-AzRoleAssignment` together with a filter:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object { $_.Scope -match 'resource_group_name' }
```